# How to use iis with friendly name on local network

Tags: iis

I make a web site to my local. I set bindings local.com and www.local.com. I add hosts xml to

127.0.0.1       local.com

127.0.0.1       www.local.com

So, I can connet on my pc like

local.com,

www.local.com,

192.168.1.35

But another pc on my network can't conenct with friendly name

www.local.com,

local.com,

But same pc can connet with ip

192.168.1.35

How can that another pc connect with friendly name ?

Answer (score 1):

IP Addresses are the numerical identification for each device on a computer network.

Named Addresses invented, because remembering each device Address's turned to a difficult job.

So someone must know's which names must be converted to which IP Address.

DNS Servers are responsible to do this translation. But you done that locally. Actually you don't have a DNS Server on your local System, So you can't tell to others that "WWW.Something.COM" is my Address.

If you didn't connected to the internet, you must establish a DNS Server or done this task manually in all clients:

https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/edit-hosts-file/

Running a DNS Server is another task. you can search for DNS Server applications like https://simpledns.com/ or you can setup a DNS Server using Windows Server. for both scenarios you need to tell to your clients to add your DNS Server Address to their network Adapter settings.

or If you are connected to the Internet, you can Use a NoIP to register a free Address:

https://www.noip.com/

you then need to download an application (In Noip.com) to monitor IP changes, it will monitors your IP address and it changes and then tells to NOIP.com to translate your address into your current IP address.

**Actually NOIP will registers your address globally around the Internet network and each one who can access to the internet is able to reach to your address.**